# Creating a subset of a dataframe in R without removing NA's

Tags: css, r, subset, na

I have a dataframe and I want to exclude all rows where var2 = X, but want to keep the rows where var 2 = NA

```
var1  var2 
10    x
20    NA
30    y
```

I tried the command:

```
new_dataframe <- subset(dataframe, subset = var2 != "x")
```

My results excludes all rows where var2 = x and NA.

How can I remove all rows where var2 = x, but keep the ones where var2 = NA.

Comment: Use `df[df$var2 != "x",]`. `subset` drops NA values. Though not said explicitly for data.frames, in `?subset`, it says *For ordinary vectors, the result is simply x[subset & !is.na(subset)]*. This rule extends to the rows of the data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I tried this, and it sets all variables for all rows that don't have var2 = y to NA.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong. I got that result when trying new_dataframe <- dataframe[dataframe$var2 != "x",]

Comment: Probably need to include `& !is.na(df$var2)`, which would be `df[df$var2 != "x" & !is.na(df$var2),]`.